# Learning Blueprints, should I move directly to Tinkerpop 3?

Tags: graph, neo4j, gremlin, titan, tinkerpop

I need to learn Gremlin etc. and possibly use it within a public facing production-ready system I'm working on. **As any release of my system is, at a minimum, 6 months away (say end Q1 2015), should I switch directly to the new, still pre-release, Tinkerpop 3 implementation, now?**

I'd rather not mis-use development time writing code against Tinkerpop 2 if it's all going to change within a year or so, however, I'm also wary of using untested code, for production purposes.

Any feedback or ideas would be very helpful ;-)

Comment: Consider posting this question on the gremlin-users mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users

Comment: Thanks, I've posted over there, I got a quick and precise answer from Marko Rodriguez, one of the Tinkerpop lead developers, see my answer below.

Comment: I probably could have answered for you here - just trying to comply with Stackoverflow rules.  Glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I went over to the [Tinkerpop Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/afg7nSP_ikg), as suggested by @stephen-mallette, and Marko Rodriguez, one of the Tinkerpop lead developers, had this to say regarding moving to Tinkerpop 3 development:

> (As of 16th Sept 2014)
>
> Here are my thoughts.
>
> 1. TinkerPop3 M2 is days away so start coding to that when it comes out.
> 2. **If you are using Neo4j**, you will be a in great position for TinkerPop3 usage -- as **TinkerPop3 GA is then maybe 1 month away** and
>      Neo4j is a reference implementation of TP3.
> 3. If you are using any other backend, you will most likely see their TP3 implementations coming by years end. ?? (up to the vendors)
> 4. If you are using Titan, then Titan 0.9 will come out within 1-2 months with TP3 support.
>
> In short, avoid using TP2 if you can.
>
> HTH, Marko.
>
> http://markorodriguez.com