# How can we use Tinkerpop Blueprints in Orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint, tinkerpop-frames

I want to use Blueprints and Pipes in OrientDB. 
What is the method? And also TinkerPop3 or TinkerPop2? Which is better for my learning experience?

Comment: Main difference between tinkerpop 2 and 3 is integrity. 3rd version is packed to one library only with name `tinkerpop`. Tinkerpop2 is set of 6 subprojects , and any of these subproject can be used separately.

Answer (score 7):

The latest versions of OrientDB natively implement the Blueprints API, so you are "using Blueprints" by virtue of using OrientDB.  Pipes is a general dataflow framework and can be used with any Blueprints graph.  Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and add Pipes and OrientDB as dependencies in order to construct your project as maven will help manage all the dependencies for you.

With respect to TinkerPop2 or TinkerPop3, you might want to refer to this:

[Learning Blueprints, should I move directly to Tinkerpop 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25851490/1831717)

However, note that OrientDB does not yet implement TinkerPop3, so if you are only interested in that backend, you will have to work in TinkerPop2 for now.

UPDATE: There is a third-party maintained TinkerPop 3.x implementation for OrientDB which can be found [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin).

Comment: Can you give me a link to download Maven i did not know even the word before?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to maven.  I suggest that if you have not used Maven before (or aren't generally familiar with development for the Java ecosystem), you focus on learning that before digging too deeply into TinkerPop and OrientDB.

Comment: Added a link to the third-party maintained OrientDB implementation of TinkerPop 3.x

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OrientDB 1.7.X and you're using the Graph API, then you're already using [Blueprints 2.5.0](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html). [Gremlin 2.5.0](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Gremlin.html) is included as well. Other useful documents include:

- [Blueprints Wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki)
- [Gremlin Wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki)